# Proving or disputing existence of required linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I came across the following question which seems fairly easy, but I'm afraid that I'm missing something.

> There is a linear transformation $T:\ R_3[x]\to\mathbb{C}$ where both spaces are over $\mathbb{C}$ such that $$T(x-x^2)=1,T(x)=1+i,T(x^2)=i$$

As far as I know, one requirement should be that $T(0)=0$, but in this case, we can get $3$ possible values where none is zero, this such linear transformation is not exist. Also, if $T$ is linear transformation, then $T(x)$ is a single value and in this case for $x=0$ we get three possible values, for $x=1$ or $x=0.5$ we get two possible values.

Am I missing something or such transformation really not exist?

Thank you!

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the definition of $T$. It assigns a complex number to each polynomial of degree $\le3$, so it doesn’t make sense to plug in values for $x$. That’s just a dummy variable. Try expressing the polynomials as coordinate vectors w.r. the basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ instead. Then, you have $T(0,1,-1,0)=1$, $T(0,1,0,0)=1+i$ and $T(0,0,1,0)=i$. Can you answer the question now?

Comment: BTW, $T(0)=T(x-x^2)-T(x)+T(x^2)=1-(1+i)+i=0$, so $T$ can’t be rejected on that basis.

Comment: @amd, thank you. Actually, we defined $R_3[x]$ as the space of polynomials of degree $\le 2$, thus the basis would be $\{1,x,x^2\}$. Now, I can define $T(1)=1$ (or any other value) and then I will have $T(1,0,0)=1$, so if I write $T(ax^2+bx+c)=m+ni$ and using the given values I can find that $m=a+b+c,n=a+b$, hence $T(ax^2+bx+c)=(a+b+c)+(a+b)i$. Is it correct?

Comment: That’s good, but perhaps more work than necessary for the exercise. It would’ve been enough to confirm that $T(x-x^2)=T(x)-T(x^2)$, otherwise you’d have a violation of linearity. You can write up an answer to the question yourself now ;)

Comment: @amd, I thought about this question once again. We know that $R_3[x]$ is not a vector space over $\Bbb{C}$. I think there was a typo in the question and it should be $C_3[x]$, otherwise we can't  find such transformation. In the question we are told that the spaces are over $C$, how should we use it?

Comment: Mapping from $\mathbb R_3[x]$ to $\mathbb C$ is fine. Nothing about how you solve the problem changes if the domain is $\mathbb C_3[x]$, though.

Comment: @amd, just to clarify, we should omit the fact that both spaces are over $\Bbb{C}$ (because $\Bbb{R}_3[x]$ is not)?

Comment: Treat $\mathbb C$ as a vector space over $\mathbb R$.